# Grammatical rules pertaining to 'number shifts'

Tags: verb-agreement

Thanks everybody for your enthusiasm for my previous questions. Now I have an additional question pertaining to a particular section of English grammar: "number shifts"

For example:

- The problem with this plan **is** all of the permits we could have to file before starting the project.

It is obvious that neither the word "is" or "are" is consistent with the noun each of them refers to. Therefore, how can I solve this dilemma? After a moment of thinking the solution, I got exhausted; therefore, I decided to get rid of this kind of confusion by changing the whole sentence into a somewhat new one:

- Filling all of the permits required by this plans will probably delay the project.

However, I was still not satisfied with my attempt. So, can somebody give me some advice on how to tackle this kind of situation? Should I change the form of the sentence without changing its meaning or is there a correct way using the word "is" or "are"? If I needed to adhere to the latter approach, what would I essentially do to avoid the mismatch between "noun" and "verb"? Once again, thanks for any help!

Best regards

Comment: Your first sentence seems completely fine to me, as your usage of 'is' is due to *problem* being singular.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem really. In your first sentence, the subject is singular so the verb is singular. The subject complement is plural, but that doesn't usually affect the verb’s number (except in existential clauses)… so why is it you don't feel that _is_ works? If you wanted to avoid the plural complement, you could just say “The problem with this plan is _the number of_ permits we would [note: not ‘could’] have to file…”.

Comment: The fact is that in that sentence, I equate the phrase "the problem" with "all of the permits". Therefore, the word "is" is inconsistent with "all of the permits". Similarly, the word "are" does not match "the problem", either. I got confused simply because I read a material which talk about some subtle grammartical mistakes,

Comment: Subject agreement is with the **Subject** noun phrase, not with a complement noun phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe the subject agreement in the first sentence is correct. "Is" refers to "Problem" which is singular. If you replaced "is" with "are" the sentence would read:

> The problem with this plan are..."

which would be incorrect because, as I said earlier, problem is a singular word which needs a singular verb to follow.

Your construction change in the second sentence is incorrect for that very reason. "This plans" is an incorrect phrase because "this" - a singular pronoun - is modifying "plans" - a plural noun - and should be these. I think you meant to say "this plan." In that case the sentence would be correct.

A simple fix for the first sentence if you don't like the way it looks is to change it to

> The **problems** with this plan **are** all of the permits...

But, as for the subject-verb agreement, all three sentences are correct.

If you'd like to read more, these websites [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/) and [here](http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm) may help.

Comment: Oh god, I forgot about the word "plans" that it must have been "plan". Truly sorry

Comment: 'Plan' or 'plans' would make no difference here. "The problem with these plans is..." would still be correct.